# Java spring problem concerning JPA repositories and autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am an oldtimer, but fairly new to spring and friends (and maybe i am getting old and rusty, dont be hard on me) . I have question which is very, very, similar to the one found in the [Unable to Field identify bean named 'entityManagerFactory' as using Auto-wiring annotation to Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255958/unable-to-field-identify-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-as-using-auto-wiring#new-answer?newreg=0a3a08dd526543479634f37129d9b2c3) and it currently beats me... I am unable to find an answer as to why the springboot application (which is a silly little thing i do on my spare time) doesnt seem to be able to autowire jpa repositiories as it should. I have (to the best of my knowledge) followed the instructions in the linked issue above (and removed any known direct hibernate dependencies. I am enclosing my pom file in this public question as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>se.pointsofinterest</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-restlayer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>restlayer</name>
<description>This module contains the rest layer for the application</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>se.pointsofinterest</groupId>
        <artifactId>dblayer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
            <!-- Possibly suspect depedencies below! -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>4.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <!-- Main maven repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- Repository where to store our local artifacts (an azure artifacts)! -->
    <repository>
        <id>joakimhansson</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/joakimhansson/_packaging/joakimhansson/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As far as I know I have no dependencies on hibernate in this pom.

I have a database layer which contains;

- domain (all the entities)
- repository (all relevant repository references)
- Service which contains a service layer (which defines somewhat higher business logic for the data handling).

This is, to the best of my abilities to see very analogue to the issue referenced above.

The error i get is;

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field mapLocationRepository in se.poi.restlayer.dblayer.services.MapLocationService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

I..e the autowire function does not work.
My application configuration;

```
package se.poi.restlayer;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.*;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.AddressRepository;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.LinksRepository;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.MapLocationRepository;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.TagDefinitionsRepository;

/**
 *  * @author Joakim Hansson, 2020
 *
 */
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"se.poi.dblayer.repositories", "se.poi.dblayer.services"})
/*@Import(value={ConfigurationDbLayer.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={
        "se.poi.dblayer",
        "se.poi.dblayer.domain",
        "se.poi.dblayer.repositories",
        "se.poi.dblayer.services"})
*/
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
        Address.class,
        Links.class,
        MapLocation.class,
        MapLocationTagDefinitionsRelation.class,
        TagDefinitions.class
})

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {
        AddressRepository.class,
        LinksRepository.class,
        MapLocationRepository.class,
        TagDefinitionsRepository.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={
        "se.poi.restlayer.dblayer",
        "se.poi.restlayer.dblayer.domain",
        "se.poi.restlayer.dblayer.repositories",
        "se.poi.restlayer.dblayer.services"})

public class Application {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        log.info("Starting the main backend for the end customer for us.");
        log.info("------------------------------------------------------");
        //new BeanConfigurator();
        //AutowireCapableBeanFactory f = context.getContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        //f.autowireBean(new AddressRepository());
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The repository;

```
package se.poi.restlayer.dblayer.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import se.poi.dblayer.domain.Address;

@Repository
//@Component
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long>{
}
```

The Service;

```
package se.poi.restlayer.dblayer.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.Address;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.Links;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.MapLocation;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.TagDefinitions;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.AddressRepository;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.LinksRepository;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.MapLocationRepository;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.TagDefinitionsRepository;
//import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.ApplicationScope;
/**
 * Demo backend that accepts up to 100 fishing spots. Data is shared with all
 * users.
 */
@Slf4j
//@Service
@Component
public class MapLocationService {
    
    //private List<MapLocation> spots = new ArrayList<MapLocation>();

    @Autowired(required = true)
    MapLocationRepository    mapLocationRepository;
    @Autowired(required = true)
    TagDefinitionsRepository tagDefinitionsRepository;
    @Autowired (required = true)
    LinksRepository          linksRepository;
    @Autowired (required = true)
    AddressRepository        addressRepository; 

    public void checkRepositoryStatus () {
        log.warn("checkRepositoryStatus");
        if (mapLocationRepository == null) {
            log.warn("Repository is == NULL!");
        } else if (tagDefinitionsRepository == null) {
            log.warn("tagDefnitionsRepository == NULL!!");
        }
    }

    public void setMapLocationRepository (MapLocationRepository repository) {
        this.mapLocationRepository = repository;
    }

    public Repository getMapLocationRepository() {
        return (Repository) mapLocationRepository;
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        log.info("init called!");
    }
    /**
     * Retrieves a list of map locations to the caller. As the
     * map location is lazilly loaded the caller needs to instantiate each object
     * using @link getManagedMapLocation
     * 
     * @return list of map locations.
     */
    @Transactional
    public List<MapLocation> getAll() {
        log.info("getAll");
        //return Collections.unmodifiableList(spots);
        return mapLocationRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public MapLocation getManagedMapLocation (MapLocation mapLocation) {
        Optional<MapLocation>mapLocationResponse = mapLocationRepository.findById(mapLocation.getId());
        mapLocation = mapLocationResponse.get();
        mapLocation = getAllLinks(mapLocation);
        mapLocation = getAllAddresses(mapLocation);
        mapLocation = getAllTags(mapLocation);
        return mapLocation;
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public MapLocation getAllAddresses (MapLocation mapLocation) {
        log.info("getAllAddresses called!");
        mapLocation.getAddresses();
        log.info("Retrieved (" + mapLocation.getAddresses().size() + ") objects in list!");
        return mapLocation;
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public MapLocation getAllLinks (MapLocation mapLocation) {
        log.info("getAllLinks called!");
        mapLocation.getLinks();
        log.info("Retrieved (" + mapLocation.getLinks().size() + ") objects in list!");
        return mapLocation;
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public MapLocation getAllTags (MapLocation mapLocation) {
        mapLocation.getTagDefinitions();
        return mapLocation;
    }

    /**
     * The spot object is a non managed object as returned by this service from
     * the getAllFunction.
     * 
     * @param spot
     */
    @Transactional
    public MapLocation addSpot(MapLocation spot) {
        log.info("addSpot called!");
        MapLocation mapLocation = mapLocationRepository.save(spot);
        for (Links i : spot.getLinks()) {
            log.info("links: " + i.getLink() + " id = " + i.getId());
            i.setMaplocation(mapLocation);
            linksRepository.save(i);
        }
        for (Address i : spot.getAddresses()) {
            log.info("Address: " + i.getAddressline1() + " id = " + i.getId());
            i.setMaplocation(mapLocation);
            addressRepository.save(i);
        }
        for (TagDefinitions i : spot.getTagDefinitions()) {log.info("Tagdefinition: " + i.getTag());}
        return mapLocation;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete (MapLocation mapLocation) {
        /* Implementaion */
        log.info("delete on maplocation is called!");
        for (Links i: mapLocation.getLinks()) {
            log.info("Removing link (" + i.getId() + ")");
            linksRepository.delete(i);
        }
        for(Address i : mapLocation.getAddresses()) {
            log.info("Deleting address (" + i.getId() + ")");
            addressRepository.delete(i);
        }
        log.info ("remove mapLocation.getId (" + mapLocation.getId() + ")");
        mapLocationRepository.delete(mapLocation);
        /* * * */
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name Marker name, which should be used on the map.
     * @param links the links associated with the marker
     * @param address the address to the nearest street address
     * @param latitude
     * @param longitude
     * @param tags the list of tag (in string form) for the marker.

     * @return
     */
    public MapLocation prepareSpot (Long                 id,
                                    String               name, 
                                    List<Links>          links,
                                    List<Address>        addresses,
                                    double               latitude,
                                    double               longitude, 
                                    List<TagDefinitions> tagDefinitions) {
        /* Implementation */
        MapLocation mapLocation = new MapLocation();
        mapLocation.setId             (id);
        mapLocation.setName           (name);
        mapLocation.setLinks          (links);
        mapLocation.setAddresses      (addresses);
        mapLocation.setLatitude       (latitude);
        mapLocation.setLongitude      (longitude);
        mapLocation.setTagDefinitions (tagDefinitions);
        mapLocation.setAddresses      (addresses);
        mapLocation.setLinks          (links);

        /* * * */
        return mapLocation;
    }
}
```

And a suitable domain entity;

```
package se.poi.restlayer.dblayer.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

/**
 * Simple data object representing a marker on a map.
 */
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="MAP_LOCATION")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MapLocation implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -590067472197846904L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long   id;
    @Column(name="latitude",    nullable = false)
    private Double latitude;
    @Column(name="longitude",   nullable = false)
    private Double longitude;
    @Column(name="name",        length = 128)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany (fetch=FetchType.EAGER) //(mappedBy = "mapLocations")
    @JoinTable(name="maplocations_tagdefinitions", 
               joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="mapLocations"), 
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tagDefinitions"))
    private List<TagDefinitions>tagDefinitions = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="maplocation")
    private List<Links> links;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="maplocation")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public MapLocation(double latitude, double longitude, String name, List<TagDefinitions>tagDefinitions) {
        this.latitude       = latitude;
        this.longitude      = longitude;
        this.name           = name;
        this.tagDefinitions = tagDefinitions;
        /* * * */
    }
}
```

The test that sets it off;

```
package se.poi.restlayer;

import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.document;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
//import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.AutoConfigureRestDocs;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import se.poi.restlayer.controller.GetTagsController;

/**
 * 
 * @author fmanh
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(GetTagsController.class)
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(outputDir="target/snippets")
@Slf4j
public class WebLayerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Test
    public void testGetTags() throws Exception {
        log.info ("mockMvc == " + ((this.mockMvc==null)?"NULL":"INSTANTIATED"));
        log.info("KALLE");
        this.mockMvc.perform (get("/retrievealltags")); //.
        //andExpect(status().isOk()).
        //andExpect(content().json("")).
        //andDo(print()).
        //andDo(document("/retrievealltags"));
    }
}
```

The application.properties

```
server.port=8080

# Ensure application is run in Vaadin 14/npm mode

vaadin.compatibilityMode     = false

logging.level.org.atmosphere = warn

#
# Settings for the internal H2
#
#spring.datasource.url             = jdbc:h2:file:~/test
#spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
#spring.datasource.username        = sa
##spring.datasource.password       =
#spring.jpa.databse-platform       = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
#spring.h2.console.enabled         = true
#spring.h2.console.path            = /h2-console
#hibernate.dialect                 = H2

#
# Set up the postgres database
#
spring.datasource.url                               = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres 
spring.datasource.username                          = postgres
spring.datasource.password                          = d1d4a5baa55f4f70a90e12bc95473833
spring.jpa.database-platform                        = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql                                 = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto                       = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy       = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql          = true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug

#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
# Following values available;
# validate, update, create, create-drop, none

#server.port                   = 8443
#server.ssl.key-store-type     = PKCS12
#server.ssl.key-store          = classpath:keystore.p12
#server.ssl.key-store-password = Pur3Life
#server.ssl.key-alias          = tomcat
#security.require-ssl          = true
```

Any help is appreciated! I have tried in vain to google it (maybe my google fu is not up to par, or I have missed something obvious), if so feel free to point it out. A tar archive of the softwar
e can be obtained if you wish (there is no secrets here). Please help me grow a bit in wisdom here!

EDIT!

I realised that my description is not complete: My solution contains a restlayer which containsa the following controller;

```
package se.poi.restlayer.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import se.poi.dblayer.ConfigurationDbLayer;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.Address;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.Links;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.MapLocation;
import se.poi.dblayer.domain.TagDefinitions;
import se.poi.dblayer.repositories.AddressRepository;
import se.poi.dblayer.services.MapLocationService;
import se.poi.dblayer.services.TagDefinitionsService;
import se.poi.restlayer.model.AddressObject;
import se.poi.restlayer.model.LinkObject;
import se.poi.restlayer.model.MapLocationList;
import se.poi.restlayer.model.MapLocationObject;
import se.poi.restlayer.model.TagDefinitionObject;
import se.poi.restlayer.model.TagDefinitionsList;

/**
 * The 
 * @author Joakim Hansson
 */
@RestController
//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"se.poi.dblayer.repositories"})
//@EntityScan(basePackages={"se.poi.dblayer.domain"})
//@ComponentScan(basePackages={"se.poi.dblayer.services", "se.poi.dblayer.repositories"})
@Slf4j
//@Import(value={ConfigurationDbLayer.class})
public class GetTagsController {
    //@Autowired
    //AddressRepository a;
    @Autowired
    TagDefinitionsService tagDefinitionService;
    //@Autowired
    MapLocationService mapLocationService;
    //private TagDefinitionsService tagDefinitionService = new TagDefinitionsService ();
    //private MapLocationService    mapLocationService   = new MapLocationService    ();

    @GetMapping("/retrievealltags")
    public TagDefinitionsList retrieveAllTags () {
        /* Implementation */
        if (tagDefinitionService==null) {log.error ("tagDefinitionsService: NULL!");}
        List<TagDefinitions> list = tagDefinitionService.getAllTagDefinitionsInFull();

        TagDefinitionsList tagDefinitionsList  = new TagDefinitionsList();
        ArrayList<TagDefinitionObject> tagDefinitions = new ArrayList<TagDefinitionObject>();

        for (TagDefinitions item : list) {
            TagDefinitionObject tagDefinition = new TagDefinitionObject ();

            tagDefinition.setId          (item.getId());
            tagDefinition.setDescription (item.getDescription());
            tagDefinition.setTag         (item.getTag());
            tagDefinition.setParentId    (null);

            tagDefinitions.add           (tagDefinition);
        }

        tagDefinitionsList.setTagDefinitions(tagDefinitions);

        /* * * */
        return tagDefinitionsList;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/retrieveMarkers")
    public MapLocationList retrieveMarkers () {
        /* Implementation */
        // Retrieve all the data from the service...
        List<MapLocation> l = mapLocationService.getAll();

        // Convert to...
        MapLocationList mapLocationList = new MapLocationList ();
        ArrayList<MapLocationObject> ll = new ArrayList<MapLocationObject> ();

        for (MapLocation item: l) {
            MapLocationObject mapLocationObject = new MapLocationObject ();

            mapLocationObject.setId        (item.getId        ());
            mapLocationObject.setLatitude  (item.getLatitude  ());
            mapLocationObject.setLongitude (item.getLongitude ());
            mapLocationObject.setName      (item.getName      ());
            mapLocationObject.setLinks     (copyLinksList     (item.getLinks     ()));
            mapLocationObject.setAddresses (copyAddressList   (item.getAddresses ()));

            ll.add (mapLocationObject);
        }
        /* * * */
        return mapLocationList;
    }

    /* Private functions
     * **********************************************************************/
    /**
     * Copies data from the database model to the rest API model.
     * 
     * @param links
     * @return
     */
    private List<LinkObject> copyLinksList (List<Links>links) {
        /* Implementation */
        ArrayList<LinkObject> ll = new ArrayList<LinkObject> ();

        for (Links item: links) {
            LinkObject linkObject = new LinkObject();

            linkObject.setId   (item.getId());
            linkObject.setLink (item.getLink());

            ll.add(linkObject);
        }
        /* * * */
        return ll;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param address
     * @return
     */
    private List<AddressObject> copyAddressList (List<Address>address) {
        /* Implementation */
        ArrayList<AddressObject> ll = new ArrayList<AddressObject> ();

        for (Address item: address) {
            AddressObject addressObject = new AddressObject();

            addressObject.setId           (item.getId           ());
            addressObject.setAddressline1 (item.getAddressline1 ());
            addressObject.setAddressline2 (item.getAddressline2 ());
            addressObject.setAddressline3 (item.getAddressline3 ());
            addressObject.setCity         (item.getCity         ());
            addressObject.setPostcode     (item.getPostcode     ());

            ll.add(addressObject);
        }
        /* * * */
        return ll;
    }

}
```

This means that the application tries to instantiate a controller which contains an autowire annotation on a dblayer service, and this dblayer service in turn contains an autowire annotation on a repository. It is this chain which goes south. Sorry for the omission.

EDIT;
I am now experimenting widly; autowire simply doesnt work. SIGH!. The funny part is that I can see in my log files that 4 jpa entities are found, but I simply cant get Autowired to work with those repositories... Google seams to point to that this is a common problem, but there doesnt seem to be a clear cut solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you have @EntityScan and @EnableJpaRepositories? Why is your packaging layered like that?

Comment: The current layering was solely experimental to get things functioning. My intent is to split it to a specific module (i.e. everything in the dblayer should be in its own module, together with a configuration class). My main application class would then import the module.My use of the annotations to specifically point out the directories was solely because I didnt get things work and i started experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different versions for SpringBoot and JPA (that is wrong, you always let SpringBoot pull versions for all SpringBoot starters) - remove this line

```
 <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
```

from JPA dependency so that Spring Boot pulls the correct version from parent and let me know if the problem is still there.

Comment: My import statements now looks like;
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <!--version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version-->
</dependency>`

I.e. I removd version field. Still n odice. Autowire simply doesnt occur in the service.

Comment: I have concluded that this is a test issue. Whenever i star the application in a standalone mode everything just works. But my test setup is completly messed up and cotninuesly just refuse to autowire.

Comment: I was thinking the same but wasnt sure - you are using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` which is the way of setting up SpringTests with Junit 4, but I could see through the imports that you have Junit Jupiter (which is the next version) as your dependency. In that Test you don't need that annotation so just remove it. `@MockMvcTest` is enough.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your input Asgarov, as I said, I am trying to learn as much as possible here. I will add the complete code to a public repository shortly as well (its, for whats its worth) done as a GPL project (this is a learning tool, nothing major or revolutionary in any way). I will be back with new observations. Thanks again!